# R Markdown citation broken by fig.align and other chunk options

Tags: r, markdown, figure, bibtex, citations

I'm writing a document in R Markdown and use a Bibtex library for my citations. They work fine when I use them in the text, but give me trouble when I try to implement them in a figure caption.

The Bibtex reference is:

```
@book{TEST,
    title = {R for Data Science},
    author = {Test Person},
    year = {2018},
}
```

How it works:

````
```{r carplot, echo=F, warning=F, fig.cap="This is a Test [@TEST]"}
plot(cars)
```
````

Ouput:
[image: Working citation in figure caption]

How it gets broken:

````
```{r carplot, echo=F, warning=F, fig.cap="This is a Test [@TEST]", fig.align="right"}
plot(cars)
```
````

Output:
[image]

I've tried other code chunk options like `out.width=".7\\textwidth"` and `out.extra = 'trim = {0 1.1cm 0 0}, clip'` which both cause the citation to break as well. Chunk options like `echo=F` and `warning=F` don't seem to be a problem though.

Any Ideas how i can put figure options in the code chunk options whithout it breaking my citation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a working solution for my problem, even though I still don't unterstand how it was caused in the first place. But for anybody looking for a workaround in the future, here is how I managed to do it:

````
(ref:CAP1) This is a Test [@TEST]

```{r carplot, echo=F, warning=F, fig.cap="(ref:CAP1)", fig.align="right"}
plot(cars)
```
````

Like this, the `fig.align="right"` does not seem to be a problem anymore.